# Facebook links that exist returning page cannot be displayed error with window.open

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, facebook, ionic-framework

Certain facebook links return an error (screenshot at the bottom of the post) when opening them using:

```
window.open('urlhere', '_system');
```

on an iPhone. The links work perfectly through the browser (i.e., https://www.facebook.com/lauriermarketing/) whereas in the iOS emulator and on my phone the link returns the error included at the bottom of the post. The weird thing is that certain links, such as [this](https://www.facebook.com/Engineering/), work perfectly fine. Also, this only occurs with facebook links, twitter, youtube, etc all work perfectly normally. Any idea whats wrong?

[image]

Comment: Are you connected to facebook in the browser ? I believe this a permission issue. That you need to be connected to view this link. Also, I cannot see the link in my desktop browser too (permission issue)

Comment: You're right, I can't believe I never thought to just open the link in incognito mode, the link returns an error, so I guess that's what the issue is